# How to do a zipped SWAP in Qiskit?

Tags: python-3.x, qiskit

I have a circuit with two registers, ***m***, and ***q***.

```
from qiskit import execute, Aer, IBMQ, QuantumCircuit

m = QuantumRegister(3, "m")
q = QuantumRegister(3, "q")
cl = ClassicalRegister(2, "cl")
circ = QuantumCircuit( m, q,cl)

circ.x([q[0],q[1],q[2]])
```

[image]

How can I SWAP them, in Qiskit, in a way that the order of qubits turns to *m<sub>0</sub>*,*q<sub>0</sub>*,*m<sub>1</sub>*,*q<sub>1</sub>*,*m<sub>2</sub>*,*q<sub>2</sub>*.

Comment: What do you mean by swapping? Like, do you want a different order in the drawing of the circuit?

Comment: Not quite! I'd like to use Qiskit's SWAP gate to swap the Qubits physically (for the algorithms I'm implementing).
I was able to reorder the qubits using numpy's `zip`, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Is there any way we could do this in Qiskit? Seems to be trivial but it is actually not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about adding `SWAP` gates and then revert that swapping, you can create a circuit with the swaps in the front, then put your remapped circuit, and then finish with the inverse of the first one. Here is the process:

1. Create a circuit with the `SWAP` gates:

A transpiler pass called `LayoutTransformation` allows to create a circuit composed by `SWAP` gates that change a layout out to another one (`[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]`, in this case). It is a bit obscure to use. Let me know if you want to know more:

```py
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import LayoutTransformation
from qiskit.transpiler import Layout, CouplingMap

swap_front = QuantumCircuit(circ.num_qubits)

layout_transformation = LayoutTransformation(CouplingMap.from_full(circ.num_qubits),
                     Layout.generate_trivial_layout(*circ.qregs),
                     Layout.from_intlist([0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5], *circ.qregs))
swap_front = layout_transformation(swap_front).inverse()
swap_front.barrier() # you can remove this line. Only here for didactic purpose
swap_front.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

2. Remap your circuit to the new layout:

```py
from qiskit import transpile

new_circ = transpile(circ, initial_layout=[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5])
new_circ.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

With the parameter `initial_layout` you can choose a physical qubit for each of the qubits in your register. In this case `m_0 -> 0`, `m_1 -> 2`, ...

3. Undo the swapping:

If a circuit is invertible, you can inverse it with the method `inverse`. The inverse of the first circuit can undo the swapping

```py
swap_back = swap_front.inverse()
swap_back.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

4. Putting all together:

```py
final = swap_front + new_circ + swap_back
final.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Luciano, but is this reversible? The idea of the algorithm is to zip-swap two registers, do some operations, and then reverse the swapping before the next operations and the measurement.

Comment: I think I understand your question better now. Editing. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the update. In my first comment, I was talking specifically about  `initial_layout` and whether it is reversible. Which I guess it is not. I am familiar with `inverse()` in general.
The other problem with `initial_layout` is that I have other operations before the swap.  So it creates a layout that I don't want to start my circuit with.

Comment: transpile with `initial_layout` will convert your circuit to a "physically mapped circuit" and that's not reversable indeed. I suggest you compose your final circuit by hand... I dont fully get your use case yet.